# Angular library to use extended class from app

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-library, angular-providers

I'm trying to create a authorization library within Angular

A basic example would be this abstract class which will be in the authorization library:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export abstract class AuthService {
  abstract isAuthenticated(): boolean;
}
```

Within the library I'm creating a guard and I want that guard to use the authorization service :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | UrlTree
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {

    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      //Do something
    }

    ....
  }
}
```

Within the consuming app I'd like to extend the authorization service:

```
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppAuthService extends AuthService {

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
// Do auth checks here 
  }

  anotherMethod(): void {
    // Do something extra
  }
}
```

Within the app module I then update the providers

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthService,
      useClass: AppAuthService
    },
  ]
```

The extended authorization service works great within the app however the guard is still using the base service and returns the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
> this.auth.isAuthenticated is not a function TypeError:
> this.auth.isAuthenticated is not a function

How can I get the guard to use the overridden AppAuthService? Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't provide your abstract class. It's self-contradictory

Comment: I haven't. I have this: useClass: AppAuthService

Comment: But you also have `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class AuthService {...}`. Notice the decorator's config

Comment: Great. I think that helps